# This will only delete the first row in my table. I would like it to delete whichever row I click on using jQuery & html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know how to delete whichever table row I click the delete link in. Right now it is only deleting one row.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#deleteEvent").click(function(e) {
                $("#drow").remove();
                return false;
            });
    </script>
```

The html is here

```
<div id="students">
        <table>
            <caption>Students</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Student ID</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="drow"><td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>1234</td><td>john.doe@gmail.com</td><td><a      href="#" id="deleteEvent">Delete</a></td></tr>
            <tr id="drow"><td>Amy</td><td>Adams</td><td>234234</td><td>amy.adams@hotmail.com</td>   <td><a href="#" id="deleteEvent">Delete</a></td></tr>
            <tr id="drow"><td>Megan</td><td>Huffman</td><td>12255</td><td>amy.adams@hotmail.com</td><td><a href="#" id="deleteEvent">Delete</a></td></tr>
        </table>
        <a href="#" class="addRecord">Add Record</a> 
    </div>
```

Comment: It's wrong to use duplicated ID's... Use classes instead.

Answer (score 4):

You're re-using `id` values in your HTML, which is invalid.  Given that, the behavior of anything selecting those `id`s is undefined.  This, for example:

```
$("#drow").remove();
```

It might delete the first `#drow`, it might delete all of them, it might delete none of them, it might throw an error, etc.  Since the markup is invalid, the behavior is undefined.

So the first thing you'll want to do is not re-use `id` values in the HTML.  The HTML you show could use `class` values instead:

```
<tr class="drow">
```

Or, you might not need the `id` or `class` at all...

If the delete button is inside the row then you can reference the row relative to the button that was clicked with this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

This will start at the element which invoked the event and traverse the DOM upwards until it finds the first `tr` element, then remove that element.

---

**Edit:**  You also are using duplicate `id`s on your `a` tags:

```
<a href="#" id="deleteEvent">
```

You can replace them with a `class`:

```
<a href="#" class="deleteEvent">
```

And change your selector to:

```
$(".deleteEvent").click(function(e) {
    // code
});
```

Or you can probably remove the `id` or `class` entirely since you can still identify the elements without it:

```
$("#students a").click(function(e) {
    // code
});
```

Comment: This still only deletes the first one in the table and then does not allow me to delete anymore

Comment: @Tator: Are you still using duplicate `id`s?  For example, on the `a` tags?:  `id="deleteEvent"`  Duplicate `id`s are *invalid*, so the behavior is undefined.

Comment: How would I use different ones?

Comment: @nevermind: That jsFiddle appears to be working.  Though keep in mind that you still don't really need the `class`es at all.  You can identify the target elements without them, so removing them makes the markup a little cleaner.

Comment: :) I've posted fiddle when OP asked how to use classes, before your update... However, #students a and closest('tr') are sufficient in this case ...so, i guess i can remove my comment. ;)

Answer (score 1):

USE THIS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#deleteEvent").click(function(e) {
                $(this).parent('tr').remove();

            });
    </script>
```

Comment: This will remove the `a`, not the `tr`.

Comment: try this i changed add parent for remove tr

Comment: @HarutyunAbgaryan: I'm pretty sure `.parent()` only traverses one level in the DOM, so this would remove the `td` instead of the `tr`.

Answer (score -1):

please replace your function with function given below. its working. I have checked it.

```
$(function() {
    $("table a").click(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```